# How can I select the drop down fill-in text with keyboard in Excel 2008?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2008

I have a spreadsheet of files and when I need to insert new filenames, Excel very handily produces a drop down list of similar entries. Pressing enter autofills, but then I have to click the cell to add in further text.  Any way to accept the auto fill and still be active in the cell to type in more?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pressing enter, press <kbd>F2</kbd>, then either <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> and you should be able to continue typing without moving to another cell.